# How to perform a subquery in django's queryset for the following SQL-query?

Tags: django, django-models, subquery, django-queryset

```
class food(models.Model):
    restor_id = models.ForeignKey(restro, default='', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    food_id = models.CharField('Food ID', max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    food_name = models.CharField('Food Name', max_length=50, default='')
    food_category = models.CharField('Food Category', max_length=50, default='')
    food_type = models.CharField('Food Type', max_length=50, default='')
    food_price = models.IntegerField('Food Price', default = 00)
    delivery_time = models.IntegerField('Delivery Time', default = 00)
    
class cart(models.Model):
    user_id = models.CharField('User ID', max_length=50)
    food_id = models.CharField('Food ID', default='', max_length=50)
    quantity = models.IntegerField('Quantity', default = 1)`


cart_details = cart.objects.filter(user_id = request.user.username).values_list('food_id').all()

food_details = food.objects.filter(food_id__in = cart_details).values('food_id', 'food_name', 'food_price', 'delivery_time', 'quantity')
```

I tried the above query but I am not getting 'quantity' in 'food_deatils' variable.
I want ('food_id' 'food_name', 'food_price', 'delivery_time', 'quantity') inside a same query

Answer (score 2):

You may want to rethink the way you have built your data-models (except if there is a good reason you must do it this way) and perhaps take advantage of some of Django's built-in features.

More specifically, I would suggest at looking:

- [How to build models & relationships between models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/)
- The Queryset API reference, more specifically [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) and [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)